# Postgres NOW(): can it be in the past?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, race-condition

Say I have a column `last_updated` that is always populated with `NOW()`. It is guaranteed that a row won't be set to value that's in the past from the point of view of other connections? For example, say I have a query

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE last_updated < NOW()
```

that returns a single row with a `last_updated` corresponding to `10:10:10`. Does this mean it's impossible for another row to be added with a `last_updated` corresponding to `10:10:09`? If it can happen in some cases, is there a way to make it impossible/mitigate the risk?

Context: a HTTP endpoint that is used as a poll target for latest updates. It depends on a property where if a rows are returned from the query with a certain `last_updated` times, then to ensure updates aren't missed, other changes must have their `last_updated` time *after* those of all the rows returned.

The actual query is more like below. If the last item in a poll result had a `last_updated` timestamp of `1575452913`, and `id` of `123`, then the next poll does something like the below.

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE (last_updated, id) > (1575452913, 123) AND last_updated < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM NOW())
ORDER BY (last_updated, id)
LIMIT 500
```

The `>` in the above is where the race condition comes in. If rows have been added with a `last_updated` of *before* `1575452913`, then they will be missed.

What I *think* I want, is instead of `NOW()`, some function that returns the earliest possible `NOW()` time of all open transactions?

```sql
last_updated < EARLIEST_NOW_OF_OPEN_TRANSACTIONS()
```

I realise it's a very similar situation to https://timerwich.com/posts/2018/01/29/monotonically-increasing-ids-in-postgres/. They want to guarantee monotonically increasing IDs, and I want the same but with timestamps. Ah: and I now see https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/9227 which discusses similar issues, albeit for a different database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NOW()` returns the date of the current transaction start. So if another transaction started earlier, `NOW()` can return an earlier date.

You could use instead `clock_timestamp()`.

See details in [Date/Time Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE).

Comment: Would `clock_timestamp` entirely eliminate the race condition? I realise, the transactions could be committed out of order?

Comment: There is no concept of a "later" or "earlier" row in PostgreSQL. If you use `clock_timestamp()` to initialize a row, that row determines the order you want. Remember that `INSERT`s can happen concurrently, where one new row doesn't see the other new row.

Comment: What is sure is that `clock_timestamp` is never in the past on the same system (unless system clock is changed): everytime you call it it gives the current timestamp of the system clock.

Comment: "clock_timestamp is never in the past on the same system": yes, but I would imagine that once Postgres calls clock_timestamp, there would be some period of time before the transaction is committed, even say 5 seconds in some horrible pathological case. So, from the point of view of other sessions, rows added using `clock_timestamp` _could_ appear in reverse order?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the race condition in this case. Maybe you could detail it in a small test case.

Comment: @pifor Will think about a test case... in the meantime I have added some more detail to the question.